(Mutually) Recursive Pydantic models in Langchain
For context, I'm running python: 3.11.3, pydantic: 2.7.1, pydantic-core: 2.18.2
I am attempting to use Langchain with Pydantic JSON output parsing to make OpenAI api calls to prompt gpt4 and force the output to be in the structures I want. However, the class I want (Proof) is a list of a (mutually) recursive class (ProofStep). For reference, here is a minimum working example.
from __future__ import annotations
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field
from typing import List, Union, Tuple
from langchain_core.output_parsers import JsonOutputParser
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from tenacity import (
    retry,
    stop_after_attempt,
    wait_random_exponential,
) 


def prompt_structured(thm:str, actual_prompt:str, model = 'gpt-4-turbo', retries=6):

    model = ChatOpenAI(model=model,temperature=0)

    class ProofStep(BaseModel):
        tactic : Union[str,Theorem] = Field(description="One line/tactic in a tactic proof (str) or a subtheorem/sublemma/subproof")

    class Theorem(BaseModel):
        decl : str = Field(description="Theorem declaration")
        proof : List[ProofStep] = Field(..., description="Sequence of proofsteps for full proof of theorem.")
        
    class Proof(BaseModel):
        contents : List[ProofStep] = Field(description= "Contents of a proof, seperated into a sequence of proof steps (i.e. tactics/subproofs)")
    

    # Define the output parser
    parser = JsonOutputParser(pydantic_object= Proof)

    # Define the prompt template
    prompt = PromptTemplate(
        template= actual_prompt + "\n{data_str}\n"+"{format_instructions}",
        input_variables=["data_str"],
        partial_variables={"format_instructions": parser.get_format_instructions()},
    )

    # Create the chain
    chain = prompt | model | parser

    @retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=30), stop=stop_after_attempt(retries))
    def invoke_throttled(chain,config):
        return chain.invoke(config)
    
    output=invoke_throttled(chain,{"data_str" : thm})
    
         
    trimmed_proof = output.get('contents',[])
    return trimmed_proof

if __name__=='__main__':
    output = prompt_structured('For propositional variables P and Q, P^Q -> Q^P', 'Given a theorem statement, output a proof of the theorem')
    print(output)

Clearly, the ProofStep and Theorem classes are mutually recursive, but the forward references should be resolved by the from future import __annotation__. However, when I run this code, I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/auto-rewriting/models/prompt.py", line 236, in <module>
    out=prompt_structured(thm,length_metric())
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/auto-rewriting/models/prompt.py", line 129, in prompt_structured
    partial_variables={"format_instructions": parser.get_format_instructions()},
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/output_parsers/json.py", line 79, in get_format_instructions
    schema = {k: v for k, v in self._get_schema(self.pydantic_object).items()}
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/output_parsers/json.py", line 53, in _get_schema
    return pydantic_object.schema()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py", line 664, in schema
    s = model_schema(cls, by_alias=by_alias, ref_template=ref_template)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/v1/schema.py", line 188, in model_schema
    m_schema, m_definitions, nested_models = model_process_schema(
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/v1/schema.py", line 581, in model_process_schema
    m_schema, m_definitions, nested_models = model_type_schema(
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/v1/schema.py", line 622, in model_type_schema
    f_schema, f_definitions, f_nested_models = field_schema(
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/v1/schema.py", line 255, in field_schema
    f_schema, f_definitions, f_nested_models = field_type_schema(
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/v1/schema.py", line 527, in field_type_schema
    f_schema, f_definitions, f_nested_models = field_singleton_schema(
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/v1/schema.py", line 926, in field_singleton_schema
    if issubclass(field_type, BaseModel):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen abc>", line 123, in __subclasscheck__
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

And checking the value of field_type in the issubclass() call, I got that it was ForwardRef('List[ProofStep]').
So I added ProofStep.update_forward_refs() and Theorem.update_forward_refs() after the class declarations, and got a different error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/auto-rewriting/models/prompt.py", line 240, in <module>
    out=prompt_structured(thm,length_metric())
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/auto-rewriting/models/prompt.py", line 125, in prompt_structured
    parser = JsonOutputParser(pydantic_object= Proof)
                                               ^^^^^
NameError: name 'ProofStep' is not defined

I'm quite lost on why this issue is happening, and am looking for any fixes that preserve the mutual recursion. It seems to me the issue happens because of the forward references, but if update_forward_refs() doesn't work, my next steps are quite muddled. Any help is appreciated!
